# how to post data into api using angular

Tags: angular

My api is http://dradiobeats.x10host.com//api/areas/
Why my data isn't posting in api somebody kindly tell me . I am using postman api.

My file-upload.component.html

```html
<div class="container">
    <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">
    

        <div class="form-group input-group-lg">
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Name" formControlName="id">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block btn-lg">Create</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

my file-upload.component.ts

```html
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from "@angular/forms";
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-file-upload',
  templateUrl: './file-upload.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./file-upload.component.css']
})

export class FileUploadComponent implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    public fb: FormBuilder,
    private http: HttpClient
  ) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      id: [''],
  
    })
  }

  ngOnInit() { }

 
  submitForm() {
    var formData: any = new FormData();
    formData.append("id", this.form.get('id').value);
  

    this.http.post('http://dradiobeats.x10host.com//api/areas/', formData).subscribe(
      (response) => console.log(response),
      (error) => console.log(error)
    )
  }

}
```

My api is http://dradiobeats.x10host.com//api/areas/
Why my data isn't posting in api somebody kindly tell me . I am using postman api.
i am just getting my array back.

Comment: You have a double slash `//` after com in your url.

Answer (score 0):

You not need to send FormData because you don't have uploaded file so just do that

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from "@angular/forms";
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-file-upload',
  templateUrl: './file-upload.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./file-upload.component.css']
})

export class FileUploadComponent implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    public fb: FormBuilder,
    private http: HttpClient
  ) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      id: [''],

    })
  }

  ngOnInit() { }


  submitForm() {
    var data: any = {id: this.form.get('id').value}
    this.http.post('http://dradiobeats.x10host.com//api/areas/', data).subscribe(
      (response) => console.log(response),
      (error) => console.log(error)
    )
  }

}
```

Comment: HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "http://dradiobeats.x10host.com/api/areas/", ok: false, …}headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0)}status: 0statusText: "Unknown Error"url: "http://dradiobeats.x10host.com/api/areas/"ok: falsename: "HttpErrorResponse"message: "Http failure response for http://dradiobeats.x10host.com/api/areas/: 0 Unknown Error"error: ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, total: 0, type: "error", …}__proto__: HttpResponseBase .